Unexpected type specification while specifying gradle dependency
I'm implementing
dependencies {
...
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
}
It gives the folllowing errors and i also tried using
implementation(com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0)
it also gives same errors.enter image description here
It worked fine a month ago but now it is not working.Help me anyone

Please copy paste errors into your question rather than linking to an image.  Also, try to be more specific in your question title, as this error has nothing to do with the library you're using, it has to do with your gradle dependencies (I edited it for you here).

Based on the image you've provided, it seems that you're missing opening and closing quotation marks in order for Kotlin to correctly identify the dependency:
implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0")

Once you make that work, and given the image you provided as well, Android Studio will suggest you migrate the dependency into the version catalog file instead.
Lmk if you'd like some help with that too!
